# vba: passing a variable into error handles

Tags: vba

i have a statement:

```
on error go to label
```

however i would like to pass into the label the variable which caused the error

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you mean:

```
on error goto label
```

And no, you can't pass variables using a goto command.  However, you can check the Err.Description for details, and if you are raising your own errors, you can do this:

```
  ' Raise a custom error.
    Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError + 1000, _
        Source:="TestRaiseCustomError", _
        Description:="My custom error description."
```

So if you are raising your own error, you could set Source to the field that caused the problem.

Refer to the **Use the Err Object's Raise Method to Raise Custom Errors** section at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164019%28office.10%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Err to get the error No and Description

```
 Sub|Function SomeName()
     On Error GoTo Err_SomeName          ' Initialize error handling.
     ' Code to do something here.
 Exit_SomeName:                          ' Label to resume after error.
     Exit Sub|Function                   ' Exit before error handler.
 Err_SomeName:                           ' Label to jump to on error.
     MsgBox Err.Number & Err.Description ' Place error handling here.
     Resume Exit_SomeName                ' Pick up again and quit.
 End Sub|Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a clever way to do it. I normally have an error handeling class/function that way I can use "on error goto" to pass the error to the bottom block then call the error handeling function. The advantage of this is it's nice to have a centralised error handler but also you can customise it so in my case I pass the name of the procedure thats crashed. It's not pretty but you could if you really wanted to pass either a collection of variables (dependant on how many you have) or set up something to identify the variable based on the line number (which you'd have to add manauly...)

```
on error goto err

'Code

err:

ErrorHandeler err, "String with Procedure name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare global variables and use them in the code and in your error code.

```
Public global_variable1 As Integer
Public global_variable2 As String

Private Sub Btn1234_Click()
....
end sub

Err_abcd:                           
....
End Sub
```