# Is there code for "string for variable name" for passing to error handler

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am creating a central error handling procedure was wondering if there is any code to replace the need to manually add the name of the procedure as a string in every procedure to pass it to the error handler as shown in this question:

[vba: passing a variable into error handles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227526/vba-passing-a-variable-into-error-handles/4275298#4275298)

so rather than:

```
Call ErrorHandler(CStr(err.Number), CStr(err.Description), "ProcedureName")
```

is there something like:

```
Call ErrorHandler(CStr(err.Number), CStr(err.Description), myproj.mymodule.thisprocedure)
```

I haven't been able to find this anywhere, so just wanted to check if it was possible.

I'm using **Word 2010 VBA** by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to check out this [Q&A here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792134/get-name-of-current-vba-function)

Also, [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/442252-visual-basic-applications-get-module-name.html) and [that](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/getting-function-name-function-currently-running-vba-t2925001.html) might help

Comment: Hi and thanks @mehow - I figured it must have been asked, just didn't search on the right terms obviously.  Thanks :-)